# Invalid Null pointer - C++ - VS2010

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, null

I am getting an `Assertion failed` error stating `Expression: invalid null pointer` and it points to `c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring line:930`.

Here is my code:

```
void main(void)
    {
    // fillMap() fills map with data from txtfile and returns map<char,int> 
    map<char, int> myMap = fillMap("file.txt");   // <- takes a string

    MyClass *myObject;
    // Code reaches here fine
    myObject= new MyClass(myMap);    // this line causes the error
    // Does not get to here
    }
```

On the line that causes the errors, I can leave the constructor() blank and just say `ptr = new MyClass();` and still get the same error. I think its something to do with my constructor anyway.

In MyClass, the constructor definition is `MyClass(char=' ', int=0)`. If I don't give them values, then I get a `No default constructor` error.

So, can someone tell me how I can trace this error in Visual Studio 2010, or provide a possible solution as to why I'm getting these problems?

PS, it won't let me create new objects that aren't pointers, `Error: No operator "=" matches these operands`.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: If it helps, here's line 930 from xstring:

```
_Myt& assign(const _Elem *_Ptr)
    {   // assign [_Ptr, <null>)
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Ptr);      //930
    return (assign(_Ptr, _Traits::length(_Ptr)));
    }
```

Comment: could you post the code for that constructor?

Comment: The `(char,int)` constructor is not the one you're calling.  Is there a constructor that takes a `map<char,int>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the crash happens in a function named `assign`, my suspicion is that `MyClass` (directly or indirectly) contains a pointer member but you haven't defined the assignment operator (and possibly neither the copy constructor and the destructor) properly. In fact, you write

> it won't let me create new objects that aren't pointers, Error: No operator "=" matches these operands.

If you tried to create your object like this

```
MyClass myObject = MyClass(myMap);
```

the above compiler error means indeed that there is no suitable assignment operator found to assign the temporary created by `MyClass(myMap)` to `myObject`. In this case,

```
MyClass myObject(myMap);
```

should compile (although it would probably crash the same way nevertheless).

Without seeing the actual code of the constructor you are calling, it is not possible to tell exactly why the crash happens.

Comment: There is no assignment in the statement `MyClass myObject = MyClass(myMap);`

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It was a problem in the constructor itself. I was stupidly using the same name for 2 objects of different types! One specified as private in the Class, and another declared in the contructor, so the compiler was getting confused! Very silly of me! And secnodly, I was initialising a string to NULL in the constructor, which it didnt like! I have it running now without errors. Thanks again!